# LinkedIn new post preview url not showing up

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I can post with the linkedIn Api:

```
$res = Http::withHeaders([
    "LinkedIn-Version" => "202207",
    "X-Restli-Protocol-Version" => "2.0.0",
])
->withToken($post->account->bearer_token)
->post(
    env("LINKEDIN_API") . "posts",
    array_merge(
        [
            "author" => $post->account->account_id,
            "commentary" => $post->description,
            "visibility" => "PUBLIC",
            "distribution" => [
                "feedDistribution" => "MAIN_FEED",
                "targetEntities" => [],
                "thirdPartyDistributionChannels" => [],
            ],
            "lifecycleState" => "PUBLISHED",
            "isReshareDisabledByAuthor" => false,
        ],
        $this->mapMedia($media)
    )
);
```

The problem is that when in the post description a url is present for example, stackoverflow.com, the preview card on linkedIn does not show up. I only see the link! Why is that the case, I cannot find anything in the documentation how I can make sure the link preview shows up.

Also when I try other url's with correct og settings they are not showing the preview.

How can I get this working?